# Disable predefined filename - JSON schema association

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.60.1.
In my project I use many files called `project.json` and have created my custom JSON schema for them.

When I specify my schema via `$schema` field directly in `project.json` everything works just fine.

But I want to use `.vscode/settings.json` file for that:

```json
{
    "json.schemas": [
        {
            "fileMatch": [
                "data/projects/list/*/project.json"
            ],
            "url": "./.vscode/schemas/project.json"
        }
    ]
}
```

This works too **BUT** in this case it appears that VS Code is mixing two schemas for my file, which is showing in a tip when I hover the opening `{` in editor:

1. JSON schema for .NET Core project.json files
2. [My scheme name]

This results in mixing properties and messed up hints and autocomplition suggestions.

How can I disable VS Code default ".NET Core" schema for my files and leave only my schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had [C# official extension](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode) installed.

I disabled it and everything is working just fine!
The moral is: if something goes wrong, don't forget to check your extensions!